# JavaScript Code Signing

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, code-signing

How can a user, using one of the major modern browsers, know for sure that he is running my  unmodified javascript code even over an untrusted network?

Here is some more info about my situation:

I have a web application that deals with private information. 
The login process is an implementation of a [password-authenticated key agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) in JavaScript. Basically during login, a shared secret key is established between the client and the server. Once the user logs in all communication with the server is encrypted using the shared key. The system must be safe against ACTIVE man-in-the-middle attacks. 
Assuming that my implementation is correct and the user is smart enough not to fall victim to a phishing attack there remains just one large hole in the system: an attacker can tamper with my application as it is being downloaded and inject code that steals the password. Basically the entire system relies on the fact that the user can trust the code running on his machine.
I want something similar to signed applets but I would prefer a pure javascript solution, if possible.

Comment: Wow, you have this implemented already? Way to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: It's not re-inventing the wheel, it's re-implementing the wheel. Maybe you haven't noticed but there are many different types of wheels out there.

Comment: Judging from your broad and sweeping comments re SSL in the answers so far, I call troll on this one.

Comment: I tried to justify my option in the comments below, answer the question or let someone else do it, I can't be convinced that SSL is secure because it isn't.

Comment: How do you protect your key exchange from a MITM attack? Apparently you don't seem to understand how SSL is susceptible to MITM attacks and you have come up with an implementation that is even more vulnerable.

Comment: I mentioned it in my original question, I use a password-authenticated key exchange scheme. I thought stack overflow was about answering questions not questioning the motives of the people asking them. All I wanted to know if someone has any experience with destributing trusted javascript, I know there are solutions for Netscape 4 (but almost nobody uses that anymore) and there's also http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html for Firefox. I am interested in solutions for other browsers or other cross browser solutions.

Comment: Do you honestly think you can solve a chicken and egg problem by introducing more of chickens and eggs? In this case, how is this password for the secret key now protected... The answers provided for queries here are not just for the person who asked it, but for the community. As a professional, I'd rather downvote a question, and flag it for removal (the latter only when necessary) rather than have someone else learn the incorrect way of doing security. We have enough problems in this field. I didnt want to sound brash, but it seems you are expecting people to believe you without peer review.

Comment: In a password-authenticated key exchange (such as J-PAKE or SRP) the password never leaves the client, but that is the exact reason why the client needs to make sure it is running my code. If he is not running my code all bets are off. I could tell every customer to save the login page on the disk (it is a static html file) or I could create a bookmarklet with the login page (or at least something that bootstraps the login process) but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Toni, I'm currently going through the literature on J-PAKE. But, I find it a little weird, that you are trying to choose code signing as a solution to get the client trust the server. From what I've understood about J-PAKE, there is no need for PKI in a J-PAKE solution. However, code signing relies on PKI completely. I'm not sure on where to get code samples for a J-PAKE implementation, but I'm pretty sure that would help you. It might bring out any assumptions made by the authors on practical usage of J-PAKE.

Comment: I don't need the client to trust the server, I need the client to trust the code he is running. There are several ways of doing this, but code signing is the most natural one.
J-PAKE itself doesn't need code signing because it assumes the code is already at the client.
I am not the first to stumble upon this problem, the guys at clipperz.com also have this problem but they ignore it and simply ask the user to verify the code using the md5 and sha1 hashes they provide.

Comment: Yes, the experimental J-PAKE feature in OpenSSL and OpenSSH would work due to the packaged distributions themselves being verified for. In your case, I'm not sure if you require code signing at all, if you send the scripts over a TLS/SSL connection - TLS/SSL is supposed to ensure integrity in the a similar manner to a code signing process. The other alternative is to build in J-PAKE support into Firefox and distribute a custom Firefox build :P Do update the question with your requirement for J-PAKE support. It looks a bit different reading it with the new info.

Comment: For the record: Don't roll your own crypto, especially DH like key exchange.  Also, use crypto properly (don't reuse IVs, etc.).  Prefer TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 or DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your problem, but **my first thought is to use SSL**. It is designed to ensure that you're talking to the server you think you are, and that no one has modified the content midstream. You do not even have to trust the network in this case, because of the nature of SSL.

The good thing about this approach is that you can fairly easily drop it into your existing web application. In most cases, you can basically configure your HTTP server to use SSL, and change your `http://` requests to `https://`.

Comment: One more note about DNS spoofing, because it is so commonly brought up when talking about SSL and man-in-the-middle attacks. Even if an attacker spoofed a DNS response and pointed your users to a malicious web server, the malicious server would still need the correct certificate on their end. When they fail to produce the correct certificate, the user's browser will throw up all sorts of red flags.

Comment: SSL has many weaknesses, mostly because it's complex, so my system is designed to replace ssl in my application (but it is not a replacement of ssl in general).

Comment: Many weaknesses? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The web is filled with examples. While I can't break SSL myself there are published papers about chosen plaintext attacks or known plaintext attacks, downgrade attacks and others. It may be safe "enough" for some applications but not for mine.
The truth is that most (all?) weaknesses are implementation specific, but that is why I want my own implementation.
I also need to authenticate the users using a password, I don't know of any browser providing support for decent password authentication schemes, and even if they had support for them I need to control the user interface too.

Comment: The fact is that SSL is "safe enough" for basically every major business on the web today. Every time you buy something online, you're using SSL. Every time you log into your web-based email, you're using SSL. Every time you check your bank account online, you're using SSL. If the companies in any of the above situations aren't using SSL, switch immediately.

It sounds like you have your mind set on writing your own solution, so I'm not going to waste any more time convincing you that you're wrong (sorry to be so blunt). Eventually you'll learn it (the hard way) on your own. Good luck to you.

Comment: @Toni was correct. I direct you to many articles by cperciva.  SSL is a complex beast.  If you know what you're doing, "copy & paste" known good crypto results in a simpler solution... and a smaller threat surface.  Mere mortals should stick with popular TLS/SSL libs.  http://www.bsdcan.org/2010/schedule/attachments/135_crypto1hr.pdf

Comment: Discussion about whether to use SSL or not https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1183308   FWIW: Appeal to popularity is a logical fallacy.  It takes a long time and lots of active research to add confidence that a particular lib is more or less secure, but security is an unending spy vs. spy comment. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is an old, open question but the answers seemed to not do this justice.

https:// provides **integrity**, **not true identification nor non-repudiation**.

I direct you to http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Don't do crypto in JS, because a malicious injected script can easily grab passwords or alter the library.  SJCL is neat, but it offer a blatantly false sense of security (their quote, and quoted by above)

> Unfortunately, this is not as great as in desktop applications
>   because it is not feasible to completely protect against code
>   injection, malicious servers and side-channel attacks.

The long-term issue is that JavaScript lacks:

1. Uniformly working const
2. The ability to make objects deeply const and not reprototypable.
3. Code-signing

   `// codesign: cert:(hex fingerprint) signature:(hex MAC)`

   Certs would be managed similar to CA certs.  MAC would be used with appropriate sign/verify constructions.
4. Crypto, clipboard stuff are reasons to have JavaScript native plugins (signed, of course)

Getting JavaScript engines to all implement a standard is another thing, but it's doable an it's absolutely necessary to end a large swath of malware.

Comment: ECMAScript 6 now has 1 & 2 :)

Comment: CSP and SRI can reduce a lot the risk of code injection. WebCrypto was almost the solution for 4. Code-signing can be simulated with service workers: make a loader script which loads a signed script, then use "update" events to alert the user if the loader script was maliciously modified (or, if the spec allowed, prevent it).

Answer (score 0):

You could have an external Javascript file which takes an MD5 hash of your login JS, and sends an Ajax request to the server to verify that it is correct and up-to-date. Use basic security or encryption practices here - public/private keys or some other method to be sure that the response came from your server.

You can then confidently display to the user that the client-side scripts are verified, and allow the login script to proceed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution but I think that would just shift the trust on the verifying script. The entire reason I wrote this system is to avoid SSL, both for performance and security reasons.

Comment: @Toni: There is a reason TLS/SSL is the industry standard for dealing with this specific problem. It provides very high security at a relatively low cost. Sure, there is a performance hit when using SSL, but it is not enough of a performance hit to justify rolling your own Javascript-based solution. Regardless of what Javascript solution you come up with, you are going to have a tough time preventing DNS spoofing from breaking the whole thing. With SSL, it just works.

Comment: If the industry standard is so secure how come there are so many security problems? 
I have studied the alternatives very carefully before going this route, even if TLS was more secure than my custom system, it lacks the control I need for my application. I appreciate your advice nonetheless.

Comment: @Toni: Can you list some of the security problems you're talking about? Most of the problems with SSL were the result of absurdly short key lengths, or browser security holes, none of which are problems with SSL itself. The underlying protocol is quite secure.

Comment: Check my reply to William Brendel